# テーブル名とカラム名のつけ方について

Tags: データベース設計

ステータスを保存するテーブルを作ろうと、`order_statuses`を作り、`status`カラムを作成したのですが、実際に値にアクセスしようとした時に、`order_status.status`のような感じで`status`が連続するのにすごい違和感があります。
この場合、どのようにテーブル or カラムを命名したら、よりわかりやすくなるでしょうか？

```
order_statuses:
  user_id
  order_id
  status (enum: approved, declined)
  comment
```

#### 追記

1つのorderに複数のユーザーがapproved, declinedを設定できます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1つのorderに複数のユーザーがapproved, declinedを設定できます。

ということですが、
「order: ラーメン食べる？」
「user_1: approved, user_2: declined」
 のようなイメージで良いのでしょうか？
だとすると、テーブル名は order_users という手もあるかと。

```
order_users:
  user_id
  order_id
  status (enum: approved, declined)
  comment
```

使い方としては下記の感じでしょうか。

```
SELECT * FROM order_users WHERE status == `approved`
```

ただ、これだと `order に対する user の集合` という意味になってしまうので、`ステータスを表現したいんだ!` ということであれば、概念として適切ではないかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

order の status というと、発注済み、発送済み、納品済みなども連想されるので、テーブル名を `order_approvals` などに変えてはどうでしょうか。

```
order_approvals:
  user_id
  order_id
  status (enum: approved, declined)
  comment
```

Comment: +1 提示された要件を見る限り order に対するプラス・マイナス票を集約する目的のテーブルだと思われますので、status という漠然とした名前でなく役割を明確にしたテーブル名が望ましいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

order_statusテーブルの名前から推察できるのは「orderの状態に特化した管理」かなぁと思いましたが、他のカラムから推測するに、ユーザIDとorderIDもありましたので、orderそのものを管理するテーブルではないだろうかと思いましたので、テーブル名からstatusを外した方が理解しやすいでしょうか。

ところでSQL文ではORDERは予約語ですので、つけるとすれば、item_order でしょうか。

参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！すみません、説明不足でした・・1つのorderに対して、複数のuserが承認、否認のようなステータスを設定できます。そのため、別テーブルに分ける必要がありました。

Answer (score 1):

単に value としてしまってもいいかもしれませんね。
sqlのvalues句と紛らわしくなるなら status_value とかでしょうか。

ちなみにmagentoなどではそのまま status を使っているようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！valueはちょっとわかりずらい気がしたので、悩んです。magento、ちょっと見てみます！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

例えば・・・ユーザーが何かを提案し、それに対し複数のユーザーが承認・却下を回答し、いくつか回答が集まった時点で結果が決まる、というのを考えてみました。

```
提案:
  提案内容
  提案者
  状態 (レビュー待ち, 承認済み, 却下済み）

# あるいは
#
# 状態 (レビュー待ち, レビュー済み)
# 結果（承認, 却下)

提案のレビュー履歴:
  レビュアー
  対象となる提案
  レビュー結果 (承認, 却下)
```

status は対象の状態を表すものでしょうから、（履歴は別ですが）独立したテーブルを形成するのではなく、列として考えるのが適切かと思います。なので、

> 1つのorderに複数のユーザーがapproved, declinedを設定できます。

何の status や comment なのかを考え、それをテーブル名に使うべきではないでしょうか。もしその結果 `**_status` になるようなら、 `status` を使わない呼び方を考えます。